# App freezes when uploading pictures to server

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I made an app only to take photos and send these to the server. in those photos, I edit the date in the right bottom corner. If a user takes more than 9 photos the app freezes in the process and asks if you want to close the app. You can choose between close app or wait. Click on wait and the process works all the photos saved to the server. But it's annoying and not professional to get this message. Below is the code and maybe some of you can spot the mistake I made.

I use the Tcameracomponent for making photos.
A TMSFMXtableview(TV1) to show the photos in the app.
And I use the Timage for linking to the Tcameracomponent.

This is the code for the save button onclick.

```
procedure TFMmain.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
VAR
 B: TBitmap;
 R : TRectf;
 LMemStream: TMemoryStream;
 i2,I,AN, NewWidth, NewHeight : Integer;
 lExtensie : string;
 Scale : double;
 Fid : Integer;
begin
   Cameracomponent1.Active := false;
   button11.Visible := false;
   button10.Visible := true;

   if TV1.Items.Count>0 then
    begin
    for I := 0 to tv1.Items.Count-1 do    
      begin
        B:= TV1.Items.Items[i].Bitmap;
        R.Create(B.Width - 250, B.Height - 100, B.Width, B.Height);
        B.Canvas.BeginScene;
        try
          B.Canvas.Font.Size := 40;
          b.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.red;
          B.Canvas.FillText(
            R, DateToStr(Now), False, 100, [TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft], 
            TTextAlign.Center);
        finally
          B.Canvas.EndScene;
        end;
        LMemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
        try
          TV1.Items.Items[i].Bitmap.SaveToStream(LMemStream);
          storedprocFotoUp.Params[0].AsStream :=LMemStream;
          LMemStream.Position := 0;
          storedprocFotoUp.ExecProc;
        finally
          Lmemstream.Free; 
        end;
      end;
    tv1.Items.Clear;
    button11.Visible := true;
    button10.Visible := true;
    Cameracomponent1.Active := true;
    end
    else
    begin
    button11.Visible := true;
    button10.Visible := true;
    Cameracomponent1.Active := true;
    end;
   end;
end;
```

**The storedprocfotoup is a procedure on the server side.**

```
Procedure TServermodule.SavePhotoToServer(Stream: TStream);
const
   BufSize = $8000;
var
Today : TDateTime;
   Mem: TMemoryStream;
   BytesRead, Vnr,Fnr: Integer;
   Buffer: PByte;
   fFilename, lExtensie, DT, Time: String;
begin
 Today := NOW;
Flocation:= 'C:\test\';
lExtensie := '.jpg';
Time:= IntToStr(Yearof(Today))+IntToStr(Monthof(Today))+IntToStr(Dayof(Today))+IntToStr(Hourof(Today))+ IntToStr(Minuteof(today))+ IntToStr(MilliSecondof(today));
fFilename := 'F'+Tijd+lExtensie;

 // save file to server

     Mem := TMemoryStream.Create;
     Mem.Position :=0;
     GetMem(Buffer, BufSize);
     try
       repeat
         BytesRead := Stream.Read(Pointer(Buffer)^, BufSize);
         if BytesRead > 0 then
           Mem.WriteBuffer(Pointer(Buffer)^, BytesRead);
       until BytesRead < BufSize;
      Mem.SaveToFile(Flocation+fFilename);

     finally
       FreeMem(Buffer, BufSize);
       Mem.Free;
     end;
end;
```

I hope I provided enough information.

Comment: You will have to move logic of sending data to the server to the background thread. Also why are you calling Sleep? If you Sleep on main thread, your applications will freeze even without doing anything else. And your try...finally block is completely out of order. BeginScene needs to be out of try block and EndScene belongs to the finally, but only EndScene and nothing else.

Comment: You need to free up `LMemStream` on client side for each photo to optimize memory consumption. plus why your buffer size on server is 8000 byte? Are you sure about the size of data that transferred to server?

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar please see the edited post. Is this what you mean?

Comment: @AminAlinezhad I don't know if the 8000 bytes is the right size... Do you prefer another size?

Comment: You need to send pictures inside a TThread to let the MinThread (the UserInterface one) is free to be updated without freeze.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar I saw your edited piece. Now I get by the last picture the app freezes and there is an external exception 20.  if I delete the code of Lmemstream.free the exception is gone.

Comment: @emandt do you mean that my code on the server-side needs to be in a thread?

Comment: Whether you should Free LMemStream or not depends on what storedprocFotoUp does with it when you call ExecProc. If it is not released from within that call, then you need to cleanup after the call. If it is released then calling Free would cause trouble. I haven't worked with stored procs, so I just edited that code as it was - adding try...finally as you always want to clean up if there is an exception.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar Thank you for all the help!! The uploading to the server goes a lot faster now. now I only need to find the solution for not freezing after uploading.

Comment: All "things" that "takes more than 1ms to be executed" needs to be done/executed in a different thread. Maybe you have to read something about TThread in Delphi. It's simple: you define/extends TThread, put all your sending logic there, instantiate it and then execute it. Obliviously this Thread cannot interact with UI (because only MainThread can directly interract with it), so you will need some "synchronization" between TThread and UI.

Comment: Code in client side needs to run in a background thread, not the server side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, comment about your server side processing that could be much simpler and will consume less memory.

`SavePhotoToServer` has a `TStream` parameter, so you can just take that stream and save it to a file, you don't need to copy data to another stream.

```
Procedure TServermodule.SavePhotoToServer(Stream: TStream);
var
  ...
  f: TFileStream;
begin
  ...

  f := TFileStream.Create(Flocation+fFilename, fmCreate or fmShareExclusive);
  try
    f.CopyFrom(Stream, 0);
  finally
    f.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Next thing you don't need is checking for `TV1.Items.Count>0` and then doing everything in a for loop. If there are no items then nothing in for loop will execute, so this check is redundant.

Eventually, if you do want to check whether there is some work to do or not, simpler way to do that is checking that first and exiting the procedure before you disable buttons.

```
procedure TFMmain.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if TV1.Items.Count>0 then 
    Exit;

  Cameracomponent1.Active := false;
  ...
end;
```

And now to the hardest part. You need to call code that uploads to the server in the background thread. Otherwise your application will freeze.

Sending single image is simple, even sending the multiple ones would not be that complicated, but you want to know when that work is finished so you can enable your UI again.

To do that I will use additional Boolean flag `Processing`, to make the code clearer, and two separate procedures `StartProcessing` and `EndProcessing` which will wrap all UI intialization and finalization code.

One of the additional problems is determining which parts of the code can be safely put in the background thread and which don't.

Working with `TBitmap` in background threads is generally not thread safe, but from what I have seen it should be thread-safe on Android. This means you can save bitmap to stream in the background thread. This will also simplify the rest of the code.

Processing logic will be split in two parts. First will draw what is needed on the bitmaps, and background thread will handle saving bitmaps to stream and sending them.

Please not, that touching UI from the background thread is not thread-safe. In this case I will directly access UI component, because the rest of the code will ensure that this list is not modified while the thread is running.

Generally, proper thread-safe code would create copies of the bitmaps in the main thread (we cannot just take the reference because bitmaps can be modified or released in the meantime), stored in separate non UI collection and then it would pass that collection to the background thread for sending. Copying bitmaps takes time and making shortcut should work in this occasion.

Another problem, specific for Android is that user can switch from your application to another one at any time and this can also interfere with your application logic. For this part I will use `FormCloseQuery`, but I have to note that I am not sure how reliable it works on Android as the OS can kill your application regardless.

So when all of the above is applied, your code workflow would look like following:

```
procedure TFMmain.FormCloseQuery(Sender: TObject; var CanClose: Boolean);
begin
  CanClose := not Processing;
end;

function TFMmain.StartProcessing: Boolean;
begin
  Result := not Processing;
  if Result then
    begin
      Processing := True;
      // other UI logic
      Cameracomponent1.Active := False;
      ...
    end;
end;

procedure TFMmain.EndProcessing;
begin
  Processing := False;
  // other UI logic
  Cameracomponent1.Active := True;
end;

procedure TFMmain.Button10Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if not StartProcessing then
    Exit;
  try
    // prepare bitmaps
    for I := 0 to tv1.Items.Count-1 do    
      begin
        B:= TV1.Items.Items[i].Bitmap;
        R.Create(B.Width - 250, B.Height - 100, B.Width, B.Height);
        B.Canvas.BeginScene;
        try
          B.Canvas.Font.Size := 40;
          b.Canvas.Fill.Color := TAlphaColorRec.red;
          B.Canvas.FillText(
            R, DateToStr(Now), False, 100, [TFillTextFlag.RightToLeft], 
            TTextAlign.Center);
        finally
           B.Canvas.EndScene;
        end;
      end;

    // run in background thread
    TTask.Run(
      procedure
      var
        I: Integer;
        LMemStream: TMemoryStream;
      begin
        try
         // iterating through UI component is not 
         // generally thread-safe and this kind of code
         // can work only in limited scenario
         for I := 0 to tv1.Items.Count-1 do    
           begin
             LMemStream := TMemoryStream.Create;
             TThread.Synchronize(nil,
               procedure
               begin
                 TV1.Items.Items[i].Bitmap.SaveToStream(LMemStream);
               end); 
             storedprocFotoUp.Params[0].AsStream :=LMemStream;
             LMemStream.Position := 0;
             storedprocFotoUp.ExecProc;
           end;
        finally
          TThread.Queue(nil,
            procedure
            begin
              EndProcessing;
            end);
        end;
      end);
  except
    EndProcessing;
    raise;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you for this wonderful example!! tomorrow I will take extensive time to go through and understand it.  I let it know if im done

Comment: After some tests with and without the draw on the bitmap. I came to the conclusion when I draw on the bitmap and save it to the location it just saves an empty .jpg. With a file size is 4.59KB. But in my Tableview I see the picture with the right date. And if I disable the prepare bitmap code. The picture is saved correctly with a file size of 1,15MB.

Comment: Are you saying that when you use TTask.Run, edited bitmap is no longer properly saved and without TTask.Run even edited bitmap is saved correctly?

Comment: Yes, The TTask.run only works if I only want to save the picture without drawing on it. At the moment I enable the `//prepare bitmaps` code' the TTask.run only saves an empty . jpg.

Comment: I edited the answer. What happens if you add TThread.Synchronize around saving bitmap to stream? This whole approach is depends on how thread-safe is working with TBitmap on Android, and it is possible there are some parts that don't play well with threads.

Comment: Thank you a lot!! it works much faster and with no app freez or error codes. I accept this answer as the solution. But do you know where  the best place is to add the code `TV1.items.clear`

Comment: Put the `Items.Clear` in `EndProcessing`.

Comment: It is possible that you will have other issues with this approach, for instance if the `FormCloseQuery` will not prevent Android to kill your application - which can happen. But in that case, you would need to completely restructure your code. Instead of sending images immediately, you would need to save images to temporary files and send those through Android background service.